# macbook pro blank display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, logicboard

I am facing the issue with my laptop as when its starts its booting and chime sound is present but the display is blank and after sometimes, the display becomes grey. Sometimes it will work fine means display is working perfectly

I tried with changing RAM, reassembled display cable, but sometimes it will work, sometimes not.

My laptop is not in warranty, I checked with the service center they said some issue with either LCD or logic board, so they have to replace and it costs similar to buy a new laptop.

If I use with an external display, will it work?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  A couple of things, it's helpful if you provide your Mac's model identifier and specs (year, CPU, Memory, etc.) to provide you an accurate recommendation.  Secondly, connecting an external display is ***exactly*** what you should do to aid in diagnosing the problem. That said, try connecting the external display and report back what your results are.

Comment: Hi ALlan ill check and let u knw.. thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Macbook Pro (Not in Warranty). Apple Genius Bar was able to get it fixed in $150. They replaced the logic board and screen. For the time being, using the external display is probably the best choice.

Comment: for me they asked $600 each

Answer (score 0):

I think that the graphic card is damaged... Apple service obviously suggest you to replace the entire logic board, but you can save some money and bring it to a eletronics lab: look for "reballing service" (means replacing the solder contacts between the gpu and the board).
It should cost you about 150$.